# Can I control the size and shape of points in netlogo plots?

Tags: plot, netlogo, point

I know how to get a point plot in netlogo by choosing plot-pen-mode to be 2.  Doing this gives a plot with tiny dots.  In other programming environments, I can choose the marker size and shape as well as the color.  Can this be done in netlogo?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. The plots in Netlogo can give you a quick look at what the data looks like but for further handling, you will need to export the data and use another program. A simple way for exporting data is using file-open, file-type and file-print to create a csv file.

```
to initiate-output
  
  if file-exists? "output-file.csv" [ file-delete "output-file.csv" ] 
  ;Make sure to start with an empty file
  
  file-open "output-file.csv"
  
  file-type "x-value," ;use file-type and a comma to stay on the same line
  file-print "y-value" ;use file-print at the end of the line      
  file-close
  
end


to generate-output
  
  let x random 10
  let y random 10
  
  file-open "output-file.csv"
  
  file-type word x "," ;use file-type and a comma to stay on the same line
  file-print y ;use file-print at the end of the line     
  
  file-close
  
end
```

Comment: Are you aware of `export-plot`? It will make a CSV for you — you don't need to code it up manually like this. The same functionality is also available on the File menu.

Comment: @SethTisue No I ewasn't aware, thank you for bringing this to my attention. So far I have never had to export a plot and only a plot from my model.